ROS AMCL Localization base_link to odom transformation extrapolation problem
I am trying to build a simple autonomously navigating robot using ROS Noetic on a Raspberry Pi 4 with ubuntu 20.04 and I am using RPLiDAR A1 as LiDAR.. I recorded a map and try to localize within that map. But when I launch the system it gives me the following warning.
[ WARN] [1716120857.858710571]: Could not get base to fixed frame transform, 
Lookup would require extrapolation 0.148251399s into the future.  Requested time 1716120857.610574007 
but the latest data is at time 1716120857.462322712, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [odom]

When I try to set a pose estimate and nav goal, ignoring the warning, robot starts spinning around itself and losing localization. The extrapolation warning becomes and error. I think this behavior is related with the extrapolation error.
When I run roswtf, I get the following;
WARNING Received out-of-date/future transforms:
* receiving transform from [/amcl] that differed from ROS time by 1.772248531s  

I have looked online for solutions and tried increasing the transform_tolerance but no success. Any idea or help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance...
Edit:
I found out that the root of the problem may be about laser_scan_matcher. When I comment it and add a static tranform from odom to base_link, there are no warnings. But still adding a static transform is not the right solution here I think.
My TF Tree:

My Launch File:
<launch>

  <param name="use_sim_time" value="false"/>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find lidarbot)/rvizconfig/amcl.rviz"/>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser_frame 100" />



  <node pkg="laser_filters" type="scan_to_scan_filter_chain" output="screen" name="laser_filter">
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find lidarbot)/rvizconfig/shadow_filter.yaml" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">
    <remap from="scan" to="scan_filtered"/>
    <param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="100"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="map_server" type="map_server" output="screen" name="map_server" args="$(find lidarbot)/maps/evim2.yaml"/>

  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
    <param name="use_sim_time" value="false"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="scan_filtered"/>
    <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
    <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.2"/>

    <param name="min_particles" value="100"/>
    <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
    <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>

    <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="update_min_d" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="update_min_a" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
    <param name="selective_resampling" value="true"/>
    
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance" value="5.0"/>
    <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams" value="360"/>
  </node>

    <!-- Move Base Configuration -->
    <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find lidarbot)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" /> 
        <rosparam file="$(find lidarbot)/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
        <rosparam file="$(find lidarbot)/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <rosparam file="$(find lidarbot)/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" /> 
        <rosparam file="$(find lidarbot)/dwa_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
        <param name="controller_frequency" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="planner_patience" value="5.0"/>
    <param name="controller_patience" value="15.0"/>
    <param name="conservative_reset_dist" value="3.0"/>
    <param name="planner_frequency" value="5.0"/>
    <param name="oscillation_timeout" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="oscillation_distance" value="0.2"/>

    </node>

</launch>

